# nginx rewrite rule for cloud foundry context based routing

Tags: nginx, cloud-foundry

Is is possible to do the following using nginx rewrite:

Convert a url from CTX_URL=http://my-cloudfoundry.com/app/home to SUB_DOMAIN_URL=http://app.my-cloudfoundry.com/home

Where my-cloudfoundry is the server running Nginx, which can currently route SUB_DOMAIN_URL, I want it to accept the CTX_URL and convert it internally to SUB_DOMAIN_URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is perfectly possible, in fact I have it working on my local copy of CloudFoundry that uses the vcap.me domain.

You need to add one simple rewrite rule to nginx.conf (on a current vcap install this is located in '~/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/nginx/nginx-0.8.54/conf'), below the server_name directive in the server block, insert;

```
if ($host ~* "^vcap.me$"){
  rewrite ^\/([^\/]+)\/?(.*)$ http://$1.vcap.me/$2 break;
  break;
}
```

Obviously you will need to change "vcap.me" to the domain you are using in your configuration.

Comment: Thanks Dan, it works but there is one small problem. Rewrite will send a redirect request to the browser, is there any way it can be routed internally without sending redirect to browser. I am trying to do this because I cannot configure sub domains in my network at work where I am trying to use cloud foundry.